# Why am I not Getting the XML Values

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML that looks like this

```
<Registered id="SOP_NBR61553">
    <RoleOfPerson>
        <PersonBirthDate>
            <Date>1970-08-11</Date>
        </PersonBirthDate>
        <PersonName>
            <PersonGivenName>TOMMY</PersonGivenName>
            <PersonMiddleName/>
            <PersonSurName>SMITH</PersonSurName>
            <PersonNameSuffixText/>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonRaceCode>B</PersonRaceCode>
        <PersonSexCode>M</PersonSexCode>
    </RoleOfPerson>
</Registered>
```

When I run this code

```
var id = custOrd.Element("Registered").Attribute("id");
var BirthDate = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonBirthDate").Element("Date");
var First_Name = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonName").Element("PersonGivenName");
var Middle_Name = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonName").Element("PersonMiddleName");
var Last_Name = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonName").Element("PersonSurName");
var Race = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonRaceCode");
var Sex = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonSexCode");
var FullName = First_Name +" "id;
```

I am not getting the values for the elements.  For example the value of FullName should be "Tommy SOP_NBR61553".  However I am seeing this string value

```
<PersonGivenName>TOMMY</PersonGivenName> id="SOP_NBR61553"
```

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: I'm no expert but, would it not be this line? to me it looks like you're only calling the first name?.. --> `var FullName = First_Name +" "id;` Would it not be something like `var FullName = First_Name + Middle_Name + Last_Name" " id;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is C# code using LINQ to XML then instead of selecting the attribute or element nodes as you currently do make sure you extract the string value, best done with e.g.

```
var id = (string)custOrd.Element("Registered").Attribute("id");
var First_Name = (string)custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonName").Element("PersonGivenName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (.Value property )like:

```
var id = custOrd.Element("Registered").Attribute("id").Value;

var First_Name = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonName").Element("PersonGivenName").Value;

var Middle_Name = custOrd.Element("Registered").Element("RoleOfPerson").Element("PersonName").Element("PersonMiddleName").Value;
```

Also one minor change in last line:

```
var FullName = First_Name +" "+ id;
```